# How to display multiple queries in different columns?

Tags: sql, average, union

is it possible to get the three results in three columns with different headlines?

```
select avg (safety_score) as AVG_SAFETY from chicago_public_schools where school_type = 'ES' 
union 
select avg (safety_score) as AVG_SAFETY from chicago_public_schools where school_type = 'HS'
union 
select avg (safety_score) as AVG_SAFETY from chicago_public_schools where school_type = 'MS'
```

in this case the result appears like this:

**avg_saefty**

48

49.52...

49.62...

thanks

Tobi

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which database you're on.

`case` should work on majority of them

```
select avg(case when school_type = 'ES' then safety_score end) as AVG_SAFETY_ES,
avg(case when school_type = 'HS' then safety_score end) as AVG_SAFETY_HS,
avg(case when school_type = 'MS' then safety_score end) as AVG_SAFETY_MS
from chicago_public_schools
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for MSSQL Server;

```
select
(select avg (safety_score) from chicago_public_schools where school_type = 'ES' ) as ES_AVG_SAFETY,
(select avg (safety_score) from chicago_public_schools where school_type = 'HS' ) as HS_AVG_SAFETY, 
(select avg (safety_score) from chicago_public_schools where school_type = 'MS') as MS_AVG_SAFETY
```